# Samba is ignoring file and directory create permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba4

I am trying to create a SAMBA share but as usual I get a bunch of permissions problems.

Here is my setup:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        security = user
        map to guest = bad user
        guest account = nobody
        #logging and debugging
        log level = 3
        log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log.%m
        max log size = 100
        debug timestamp = yes
        unix extensions = no


[datastore_share]
        path = /mnt/datastore
        browsable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        guest only = yes
        read only = no
        force user = nobody
        force group = sambashare
        create mask = 0777
        force create mode = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        force directory mode = 0777
```

I want to give unaffected access to all clients on the network. Hence the very bad-practice configuration.

It seems the problem stems from Samba ignoring the permission modes I'm trying to enforce.

Sometimes a file is created with 777 permissions and sometimes with 751. But for some reason folders are always created with 751 permissions. This means I am unable to create a file in a newly created folder. It's especially annoying because I am mostly writing to the share via Transmission and the moment the folder gets created it bombs out with a permission denied error.

Any help would be appreciated. Most solutions to this problem I found online only worked for older versions of SAMBA that will not work for me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First, please try this settings instead of yours:

```
[datastore_share]
        path = /mnt/datastore
        browsable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        read only = no
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
```

Second, if the previous settings didn't work, please try upgrading your samba to the latest version (now I would recommend **4.4.4** as it is very stable according to my tests).